# Japanese transit visa for an Indian passport holder on an F1 visa

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, japan, transit-visas

I'm an Indian graduate student on an F-1 visa currently in the United States. I will be travelling to Singapore this summer for a conference. On the return journey, I have a layover in Narita (Tokyo, Japan) for over 24 hours. I intend to apply for a transit visa for two possible circumstances as described below:

a. Step out of the airport for a few hours before catching my flight back to the States.

b. Potentially extend this leg of the trip by 5-7 days for a short stay in Japan as a tourist.

This [link](http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/transit%20visas.html) tells me that either circumstance should be possible with a transit visa. Given the above information, what do I input on the application form for Guarantor/ Inviter?

In addition, how do I, an Indian in the USA, apply for this visa? Do I have to personally visit the local consulate for a transit visa application?

Answer (score 2):

No need to put in anything in guarantor/invitor field as your purpose of visit is either transit or tourism (allowed on a transit visa), and if you stay overnight all you need is an itinerary and hotel bookings.

If you are in the US, you will likely be able to apply by mail, unless you live very close to a consulate or the DC embassy (e.g. in NYC, LA or Boston or the immediate suburbs). For details on whether you could do it, check the website of the consulate/embassy closest to you.

Comment: Can you provide credible sources? Hyperlinks?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no real reason for transfer visa you are not eligible. Tourism is not allowed by transit visa, that's incorrect information. Transfer visa requires transfer to different airport. It should be shortest possible transfer, you cannot purchase tickets with long gap if it's possible earlier one for similar price.

You cannot get any japanese visa by mail, that's also totally incorrect. You or your representative have to come in person to japanese consulate assigned to your state http://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/jicc/consulate-guide.html

Comment: It is allowed. I visited Japan on my way back home two years ago; both the arrival and departure flights are at NRT, nevertheless I was issued a transit visa.

Comment: It's also issued when transfer includes overnight because airport does not work at night.